# How to make function that returns it's inner-closure's value in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to return `downloadedImage` from `beginGetImageRequest`.

```
func beginGetImageRequest() {

    if let imagePath = thumbPath {
        request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imagePath).response(completionHandler: { (_, _, imageData, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Error downloading thumbnail image: \(error)")
            } else {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                    self.imageView.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return anything from `beginGetImageRequest`. The fetching of the image is _asynchronous_. Search on that word; this is the most frequently asked and answered form of question in all iOS programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misunderstood the request, and I edit it agian:

```
func beginGetImageRequest(completion:(_ image:UIImage)->()){

    if let imagePath = thumbPath {
        request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imagePath).response(completionHandler: { (_, _, imageData, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Error downloading thumbnail image: \(error)")
            } else {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                    completion(downloadedImage)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When you call the method:

```
beginGetImageRequest { (image:UIImage) in
        // code you need
    }
```

Comment: This will work, but you could also create a pattern where the parameter you pass to the completion is an enum with success and fail values. On success, pass the image, on fail, pass the error object. Just depends on what the caller needs.

Comment: @DavidLari I can't agree with your comment more.Of course, We  need to judge whether  it  is sucessfully or failed.

Comment: @david Lari, the question is how to pass it in swift.

Comment: @user205265, can you elaborate on your comment? Not sure what point you are trying to make. Thanks!

Comment: Like if you could give an example like Omni Ringo, it will be great.